# Does WooCommerce provide any default rest APIs for manage Cart?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am using Headless WordPress for the back end and React JS for the front end, so please suggest the best way to manage & implement woo commerce cart in react js.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default api from WooCommerce for accessing carts via the WordPress API at the moment.

However this plugin might help you:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart-rest-api-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions except this plugin?

Comment: OR please suggest to me the standard & best way that how can I manage the woocommerce cart into the React Js ?

Comment: Does anyone suggest me for custom rest apis ?